# Given $x=lnt$ how to find $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ in terms of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I got as far as finding:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

But when taking the second derivative I end up with the following mess:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$

Is there a way to simplify $\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dt}$ or am I making a mistake in my application of the derivative?

Comment: What is $y$...?

Comment: y is a function of x, and x is in turn a function of t

Comment: $y$ is the solutions to a differential equation. Solving this problem is the first step to solving the differential equation.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432955/how-do-we-take-second-order-of-total-differential
This is nearly the same as what you are asking

Comment: I don't completely understand the answers presented on that page, but I'm fairly certain that partial differentials should not be in the answer to this problem.

Comment: The partial differentials only come in because the example is slightly more general as it involves a function in more than one varible. The general idea is the same though and you should be able to pick ou the answer you need if you dig enough. See the answer I provide for a more targeted response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=g(t), y=f(x)$, so that $y=(f\circ g)(t)$.

Using Newton's dash notation for derivation, we have:

$\newcommand{\de}{\operatorname d}\begin{align}
\frac{\de^2 y }{\de t\;^2} & = (f\circ g)''(t)
\\[1ex] & = (g' \cdot f'\circ g)' (t)
\\[1ex] & = ((g')' \cdot f'\circ g)(t) + (g'\cdot (f'\circ g)')(t)
\\[1ex] & = (g'' \cdot f'\circ g)(t) + (g'^2\cdot f''\circ g)(t)
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\de^2 x}{\de t\;^2}\dfrac{\de y}{\de x}+(\dfrac{\de x}{\de t})^2\dfrac{\de^2 y}{\de x\;^2}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give a proper answer because this question has been bothering me as well and it took me a bit of thinking to resolve it. And yeah, like you said, the page I linked is confusing, it goes into far too much depth

Simplifying $\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dt}$ goes as follows:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})=$
$\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})=$
$\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

So you end up with the second total derivative being:

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$